# Can't deploy .war file using tomcat 6.0.24 and docker

Tags: tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I'm using docker and tomcat 6.0.24 and centos6.6. I want to use the "RUN" command

```
RUN /usr/local/apache/bin/startup.sh
```

in dockerfile and unpack the war, so that it can be edited through dockerfile itself.

The problem is invoking startup.sh which seems to be successful, as docker build continues after that but when I docker run the final image to spawn a container, the .war file hasnt been unpacked.

I've searched a lot and any help would be appreciated.

I tried making tomcat as a service and used source before the command to no avail.

Comment: try `ONBUILD` before `RUN` command.

Comment: isn't ONBUILD used to defer instructions to a child image?